# Variable not accessible in Included php file

Tags: php, variables, include

I have folder say 'a' and under 'a' folder I have 'b' folder.
I have scripts in 'a' folder and in 'b' folder.

## a.php

```
<?php
$var = 'ss';
include_once('b/b.php');
?>
```

## b.php

```
<?php
echo $var; // Not printing value, says undefined.
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of your file(s) and tell us if you get any: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`. Also which script are you calling ?

Comment: I am getting error 'Undefined variable'.I am calling a.php script.

Comment: if you want to access $var in b.php you should put the `include(../a.php) in b.php file`

Comment: In php v5.5.8 it works fine, How about declaring the variable in `b.php` as global: `global $var; echo $var;`?

Comment: Put both a.php and b.php if you don't like to include as user3113490 mentioned

Comment: @Sagar Are you using any frameworks ?

Comment: @Sagar Is this your **full** and **real** code which you show us here? And do you include these files into other files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine in php v5.5.8, Try declaring the variable in the `b.php` as global:

```
// b.php
global $var;
echo $var;
```

Comment: Why should OP  declare the variable as global ?

Answer (score -1):

a.php

```
<?php
 $var = 'ss';
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php
include_once('../a.php');
echo $var; // Not printing value, says undefined.
?>
```

I think it's the other way around..

Comment: I must include b.php in a.php, not visa-versa.

Comment: you are trying to access the the variable $var on a.php... so you need to include the a.php into b.php file.

Comment: @user3113490 no, he doesn't have to, if he includes b.php into a.php, it will end up like this: `$var = 'ss'; echo $var;`, which is totally fine and is valid php